# IIS Dynamic compressions doesn't work virtual subdomains

Tags: iis, dynamic, compression, subdomain, virtual

I installed and activated dynamic comressions at IIS(Top) level on IIS 8, 
When I create simple ".asp" file, I see the response compressed,
But on my virtual subdomains it doesn't work? The subdomain doesn't exist really in IIS but default webconfig includes

```
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

It's interesting, When I removed vary header from my mobile subdomain, the problem is gone.